# Create folder structure in SharePoint library using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, sharepoint, async-await

Requirement is to create folder structure from an array in a SharePoint library using JavaScript. Below is the desired structure:

```
var ary = [A,B,C]

A -> Fldr1 -> Fldr2 -> File
B -> Fldr1 -> Fldr2 -> File
C -> Fldr1 -> Fldr2 -> File
```

But currently its creating folder A,B and C in library but inside structure is being created for C only.

So result am getting is :

```
A 
B 
C -> Fldr1 -> Fldr2 -> File
```

Below code works perfect when only one item in array, but fails when multiple items.
Here I check if folder exists, then check for 2nd level, if doesn't exist create first and so on for remaining structure.

```
   async function processArray(selectedCountries) {
    await selectedCountries.map(async (item) => {       
      let promiseCntry = await checkCntryFolder(item);       
        if(flag){ //if cntry exists                      
             let promiseChckfolder = await checkFolder(tdmrkNm);
                    if(flagFldr)//if folder exists
                    {                           
                        let promiseChkSubFolder =  await checkSubFolder(appStatus);
                            if(flagSub)//if sub -folder exists
                            {                                    
                                 let createFile =  await CreateFileInSideFolder();
                            }
                            else
                            {                                
                                let promiseCreateSub =  await createSubFolder(appStatus);                                        
                                let createFile =  await CreateFileInSideFolder();
                            }                   
                    }

            }

    });
  }
 }
```

Comment: Stop using deferreds and stop using the `done` method. Use proper promises instead. What library is that, jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so finally I have got it working:

I was not passing proper arguments to the methods.
Below is the working code:

```
 async function processArray(selectedCountries) {
    return Promise.all(selectedCountries.map(async (item) => {      
    //await selectedCountries.map(async (item) => {                             
      let promiseCntry = await checkCntryFolder(item);       
        if(flag){ //if cntry exists                      
             let promiseChckfolder = await checkFolder(tdmrkNm,item);
                    if(flagFldr)//if folder exists
                    {                           
                        let promiseChkSubFolder =  await checkSubFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                            if(flagSub)//if sub -folder exists
                            {                                    
                                 let createFile =  await CreateFileInSideFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                            }
                            else
                            {                                
                                let promiseCreateSub =  await createSubFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);                                       
                                let createFile =  await CreateFileInSideFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                            }                   
                    }
                    else//if folder doesn't exist
                    {                            
                             let createFldr =  await createFolder(tdmrkNm,item);
                             let promiseChkSubFolder =  await checkSubFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                                if(flagSub)
                                {                                               
                                    let createFile =  await CreateFileInSideFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item); 
                                }
                                else
                                {                                    
                                    let promiseCreateSub =  await createSubFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                                    let createFile =  await CreateFileInSideFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item); 
                                } 
                    }
            }
            else//if cntry doesn't exist
            {                    
                     let createCntry = await createCntryFolder(item);             
                     let promiseChckfolder =  await checkFolder(tdmrkNm,item);                                              
                        if(flagFldr)//if folder exists
                        {                                 
                             let promiseChkSubFolder =  await checkSubFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                                if(flagSub) //if sub-folder exists
                                {                                            
                                    let createFile =  await CreateFileInSideFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);     
                                }
                                else //if sub-folder doesn't exist
                                {                                                                           
                                     let promiseCreateSub =  await createSubFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);                                           
                                     let createFile =  await CreateFileInSideFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                                }                                           
                        }
                        else //if folder doesn't exist
                        {                           

                             let createFldr =  await createFolder(tdmrkNm,item);
                             let promiseChkSubFolder =  await checkSubFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                                    if(flagSub)//if sub-folder exists
                                    { 
                                        let createFile = await CreateFileInSideFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                                    }
                                    else//if sub-folder doesn't exist
                                    { 
                                        let promiseCreateSub =  await createSubFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item);
                                        let createFile =  await CreateFileInSideFolder(appStatus,tdmrkNm,item); 
                                    } 

                        }   
            }

        },Promise.resolve()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop using deferreds and stop using the `done` method. Use proper promises with `then` instead.

Assuming this is jQuery, where those objects with `done` methods also have `then` methods, you can (and should) just use `async`/`await` directly:

```
async function callAry(array) {
  return Promise.all(array.map(async (item) => {
    const flag = await checkCntryFolder(item);
    if (flag) {
      const folderFlag = await checkFolder(nm);
      if (folderFlag) {
        const subFlag = await checkSubFolder(Status);
        if (subFlag) {
          await CreateFileInSideFolder();
          console.log('file done');
        }
      } 
    }
  }));
}
```

Comment: ok, I will give this a try , but since all internal methods are asynchronous, I just hope all of them executes before my loop end. I will try and let u know. Thanks

Comment: @Rooney123 If they are asynchronous, they should return promises (which makes them `await`able). If they don't, change them to do that.

Comment: I tried the suggested solution, but no difference in result, it still returns the desired result for last item of array only.

Comment: @Rooney123 Then please show us the implementations of those functions. Maybe they use some global variables or are otherwise broken. For example, a function `CreateFileInSideFolder` not taking any arguments is smelly.

Comment: Since CreateFileInSideFolder is the last level which creates file inside the folder structure, it doesn't need any argument.

Comment: @Rooney123 But how does it know which file to create where? Should all items in your loop create the same file?

Comment: Yes, same file will get stored in all folder strutures. Infact only my first level folder names are different, rest all nested folders will have same name and same file.
Folder path is there in  CreateFileInSideFolder  method.